# Export Raster from ArcMap gdb raster catalog

Tags: arcmap, fme-form, raster-catalog

I received a file geodatabase raster catalog and would like to extract the rasters as GeoTIFF.

I tried to read them in FME and save them as raster but it failed and I also tried to export them in ArcMap (select all polygons in the layer and -->data-->export but this seems to export all rasters as a single raster.

How can I batch export all raster images which appear in ArcMap when I zoom in so I get a folder of GeoTIFFs from this raster catalog?

Comment: So when you say the FME process failed, what exactly was the problem? Did it not read anything or did it not write anything, and was there an error or warning message in the log? I would suggest trying to read the file using the format "Esri Geodatabase (File Geodb Raster Catalog)" into the FME Data Inspector. There you can see what data is being read and how. Personally I haven't used this format so I don't know if it's reading the actual data or the names of the raster files. If it's the names, you can pass them on to a FeatureReader transformer.

Comment: But if you can open the data and let me know what you see (post a screenshot) it will help to diagnose the issues.

Comment: @MarkIreland: The Inspector only shows an attribute table with information belonging to the polygons, for example the name of the raster belonging to this polygon. If you zoom further in (in ArcMap) the vector polygon dissapears and the raster is shown. Strange data format...

Comment: Yeah, I guess the format is just a vector feature with link to the raster. ArcMap must handle it automatically when you zoom in. I don't see a reader parameter in FME that says follow the link and fetch the raster, so you'd have to use the name of the raster file as the source in a FeatureReader transformer. This is the closest example I can find: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/20203/how-to-read-all-feature-classes-from-multiple-esri.html